# Greasemonkey: Unset a variable

Tags: greasemonkey

This is a question that has been plaguing me for awhile.

In Greasemonkey you can use `GM_getValue(name)` and `GM_setValue(name, value)` to store persistent variables. My question is, how do I 'unset' a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unsetting it by setting it with a blank value:

```
GM_setValue(name, '')
```

If that doesn't work:

- Go to `about:config`
- [Delete the entry](http://userscripts.org/topics/1930)
- Restart Firefox
- Run the script

Answer (score 4):

[`GM_deleteValue`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_deleteValue) will unset a value set by `GM_setValue`,
starting with Greasemonkey version *0.8.20090123* (February 18th, 2009).